# Insert string of values into DB PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am trying execute this query which returns false with message that "INSERT has more target columns than expressions" which I understand, but is there a way to use array or string with values that I want to insert ? I am using postgres with PDO

```
$params = '"param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5"';
$query = $conn->query = 'INSERT INTO myTable (
               "value1",
               "value2",
               "value3",
               "value4",
               "value5") VALUES(:params)';
$query->execute(array('params' => $params));
```

Comment: You're trying to make your input be handled as a mixture of data and code. That's exactly what prepared statements are designed to avoid. Their main purpose is to isolate data from code.

Comment: The real question is how the $params came to be in that very format.

Comment: You should read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for the proper usage of prepared statements. There's too many issues with the above snippet.

Comment: Okay I am going try to read the manual and after that edit the snippet to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the statement only has a parameter for the `value1` column and its value is `'"param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5"'`, then the message says that this request needs values for columns `value2`, `value3`, `value4`, `value5`.

You could try using this code:

```
// using named placeholders
$params = array(
     "param1" => "param1",
     "param2" => "param2",
     "param3" => "param3",
     "param4" => "param4",
     "param5" => "param5"
);
$query = $conn->query = '
    INSERT INTO myTable ("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5")
    VALUES(:value1, :value2, :value3, :value4, :value5)
';
$query->execute($params);

// using unnamed placeholders
$params = array("param1", "param2", "param3", "param4", "param5");
$query = $conn->query = '
    INSERT INTO myTable ("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5")
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
';
$query->execute($params);
```

Documentation: [PHP: Prepared statements and stored procedures - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)